# Understanding a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, summation

I am trying to understand the following function:

Let ${(r_1,r_2,r_3,...)}$ be an enumeration of the set of rational numbers. For each $r_n∈Q$, deﬁne
$u_n(x)= 
  \begin{cases}
    1/2^n       & \quad \text{if } x>r_n  \\
    0  & \quad \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}$

Now, let $h(x)=\sum_{n=1}^∞ u_n(x)$.

So I tried considering $x = 0$, then $h(0)=\sum_{n=1}^∞ u_n(0)$, I know that this is some sub-series of $\sum\frac{1}{2^n}$ but i'm having trouble getting beyond that.

Thanks

Comment: @yanko It comes from a question where the aim is to show $h(x)$ is monotone on $R$ and cts on the irrationals.

Comment: I accidently deleted the last comment, you can prove that $h(x)$ is monotone directly from definition because for every $n$, $u_n$ is monotone.

Comment: Ah it is also continuous on irrationals, the key point is that if $x$ and $y$ are sufficiently close then $u_n(x),u_n(y)$ are equal for many values of $n$ I can write down a proof if you want.

Comment: @yanko Is that because you can then show it is Cauchy and so uniformly convergent and so by term by term continuity it is cts?

Comment: yes that's exactly the point.

Comment: @yanko actually i'm having trouble with the showing its Cauchy bit so would you mind giving a proof?

Comment: In fact, you don't have to prove it is Cauchy, all you need to do is to show that $h(x)$ convergence for every $x$, as you said $h(x)$ is a sub-series of $\sum_n 1/2^n$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66410/discussion-between-salamander-and-yanko).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that $h$ is continuous on the irrationals. Let $x$ be irrational, let $y\in\mathbb{R}$, w.l.o.g assume that $x<y$ (since you only work with irrationals the case $y<x$ is similar) we have

$|h(x)-h(y)| = |\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n(x)-u_n(y)|\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty |u_n(x)-u_n(y)|$

now $|u_n(x)-u_n(y)|$ is either zero, or $1/2^n$ (because $u_n$ is monotone), 
In particular, if $x>r_n$ then $y>r_n$ and $|u_n(x)-u_n(y)|$ is zero.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and pick $N$ so that $\sum_{n=N}^\infty 1/2^n<\varepsilon$ (why $N$ exists?).

Let $\delta<\min\{|x-r_1|,|x-r_2|,...,|x-r_N|\}$

Exercise: Prove that $|x-y|<\delta\rightarrow |u_n(x)-u_n(y)|=0$ for every $n\leq N$.

Hint 1:

> Hint 1: if $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|x-y|<|x-r_n|$, draw $x,r_n,y$ on the real line

Hint 2:

> Hint 2: if $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|x-y|<|x-r_n|$, if $x>r_n$ we already prove that $u_n(x)=u_n(y)$, otherwise assume that $x<r_n$, you also have that $x<y$ therefore $|x-y|<|x-r_n|\Rightarrow y-x<r_n-x\Rightarrow y<r_n$

Assuming the exercise $|x-y|<\delta$ implies that $$|h(x)-h(y)|=|\sum_{n=N}^\infty u_n(x)-u_n(y)|\leq \sum_{n=N}^\infty |u_n(x)-u_n(y)|\leq\sum_{n=N}^\infty 1/2^n<\varepsilon$$